# Zend GData Xml/Security.php file missing

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I have just downloaded the Zend GData library from http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest and when I try to run the examples I get an error reporting that the file Xml/Security.php is missing. The file App/Base.php attempts to include it and fails. Sure enough, there is no Xml directory in the library.

A search through the Zend framework reveals an Xml directory containing Security.php, which I have copied. This fixes the problem, but I'm not sure it is the right file as when I try to get document feeds using $client->getDocumentListFeed(), the program terminates (no error message, no exception, just quits).

So two questions: has anybody else had these problems and how are they fixed? I'm curious to know why the library is incomplete and whether or not this is related to the feed failing. Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you download ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: I downloaded Gdata 1.12.5, found XML was missing and then downloaded ZF2.3.0, where I found an XML folder. Should I have looked in ZF1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you downloaded only the Zend_Gdata? The XML folder is missing, you can find it if you download the Zend Framework 1.12.5 Minimal package.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I I kept Gdata 1.12.5, then downloaded the Zend Framework 1.12.5 Minimal package, copied the Xml directory from it, and all is good!

Answer (score 2):

had this error and fixed by doing this:
1. find the zendXML folder at the root of the  "Zend Framework 2.3.1 Full" right next to the Zend folder
   files sources:  http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest
  and ALSO see "Other Downloads" at bottom of page

1. copy the zendXML folder into the zend folder
2. rename the zendXML folder as XML
   then my  error went away.